# Modifying jquery.multipage.js for Left to Right transition

Tags: jquery, forms, transition

I am using the jquery.multipage.js script to create a webform of 5 questions that submits  the data on the last question. By default the transition between questions is a fadein/fadeout but the client has decided it wants the transition to slide from left to right.

The script can be found here https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Multipage-Form. The questions in the form need to be structured with fieldset tags.

I have narrowed down the part of the code that controls the transition here but I just cant get it to go form left to right.

This is the code.

```
    jQuery.fn.transitionPage = function(from,to) {

        if (settings.transitionFunction) {
            settings.transitionFunction(from,to);
        } else {
            $(from).fadeOut('fast',function(){$(to).fadeIn('fast');});
        }
        $(id + ' fieldset').removeClass('active');
        $(to).addClass('active');       
    }
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a custom transition function, with 'from' and 'to' being the 'pages' in your form. Here, I'm using jQuery animation to perform the transition for clarity around the concept, but it could be improved by using CSS transitions instead.

This is a rather quick and dirty version which gets the idea working:

http://jsfiddle.net/eJKQn/367/

```
$('#multipage').multipage({
   'transitionFunction': function(from,to){

       var w = $('#wrapper').width();
       if (!($(from).get(0).id == 'page1' && $(to).get(0).id == 'page1')) {
           $(from).css({'display':'block'}).animate({ left: +w }, 500);
           $(to).css({'display':'block', 'left': -w })
             .animate({ left: 0 }, 500);
       }

   }
});
```

Comment: Oh that's looks perfect, thank you I will give it a ago,I really appreciate the help out.

Comment: this is perfect, but one last question sorry. How would I get it to already be in position on page load rather then slide in on page load

Comment: In that case, both the from and to transitioning elements are the same, so check for that condition, and don't animate if that is the case: jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/dituq/1/ or jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eJKQn/377/

Comment: updated sample code in answer to include this conditional statement